# Why is my server certificate being rejected?

Tags: ios, ssl, keychain, secure-transport

I am trying to connect my app to a server using TLS 1.2. The server is using a certificate that has been signed by a self-signed CA certificate that is already installed on the device (I emailed the CA certificate to myself, tapped it. Now it shows up under Settings -> General -> Profiles). This was previously working in my app, but we have changed the CA certificate we're using so I've updated the server's certificate as well. Now I'm getting SSL failures.

The error I'm seeing is `errSSLXCertChainInvalid` from my call to `SSLHandshake` on the client. As far as I can tell, the server certificate should be valid. `openssl verify -CAfile ca-cert.pem server-cert.pem` returns `OK`, and that ca-cert.pem is the same CA certificate I've installed on the device.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some information in apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html) regarding this error:

> `errSSLXCertChainInvalid` — The peer has an invalid certificate chain; for example, signature verification within the chain failed, or no certificates were found.

And if you use `SSLSetPeerDomainName`:

> You can use this function to verify the common name field in the peer’s certificate. If you call this function and the common name in the certificate does not match the value you specify in the peerName parameter, then handshake fails and returns errSSLXCertChainInvalid.

I'd suggest uninstalling your device configuration profile, and creating a new one.

Also, it might be a good idea to check if you can access the server without errors from, say, a web browser. This will reveal if there is a problem with the certificate, or just your configuration profile on your iOS device.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there was something wrong with the CA certificate profile. After deleting it and re-downloading the certificate file the connection is working. I had probably installed the CA certificate from the wrong SSL format file. A PEM file with just the CA certificate seems to have installed the correct profile.